# Shibboleth IDP with ADB2C integration

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml, shibboleth, federated-identity

We have a requirement to configure Shibolleth as a SAML IDP to ADB2C Service Provider. Does anyone have any links or working examples? I found a reference on configuring SAML IDP in ADB2C custom policies, but not any examples of what needs to be done on Shibolleth side.

Comment: The last time I checked Shibboleth doesn't allow metadata import but the info. you need to configure it is all in the B2C metadata - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-your-saml-identity-provider

Comment: Sorry - not a Shibboleth guru :-(

Comment: It needs to be configured on both sides. For B2C to connect to Shibboleth as SAML IDP (which is well documented in MS B2C docs) and for Shibboleth to recognize B2C as SP (which I am looking for instructions on).

Comment: Found only this https://coder-question.com/cq-blog/451496

Answer (score 0):

Please check if references give an idea to work around:

1. This example in ms docs : [AADB2C
   -identity-provider-salesforce-custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-salesforce-custom?tabs=applications) of how to federate azure ad b2c with any SAML idp.
2. Also check [Use Shibboleth Identity Provider to implement single
   sign-on | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/azure-services/jj205456(v=azure.100))

Else you might want to raise a support request .